# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' (Logistic regression)

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this predict code in a juypter notebook it runs perfectly and I tested it by `predict([1,2,1,0,1], [.4,1,3,.01,.1])` in a separate file, I get the correct answer of`0.995929862284` but when the use the unit test I receive the error below.

```
def dot(X, Y):
   if len(X) != len(Y):
      return 0

   return sum(i[0] * i[1] for i in zip(X, Y))

def predict(features, weights):
  x = dot(features, weights)
  return logistic(x)
```

---

```
def test_predict(self):
    model = [1,2,1,0,1]
    point = {'features':[.4,1,3,.01,.1], 'label': 1}
    p = predict(model, point)
    self.assertAlmostEqual(p, 0.995929862284)
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Hey @LewisRa, can you add line numbers to your code? I'm not seeing any code that should produce this error and it would helpful to see exactly where the error is being thrown.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `predict`, you pass a `dict` as the second argument. However, `predict` passes that argument as-is to `dot`, which expects a list of numbers instead. As a result, `dot` iterates over the keys of the dict, rather than the values of that dict's `features` value. `predict` should be called as `predict(model, point['features'])` instead. (Or perhaps `predict(point['features'], model)`, given the parameter names.)

Answer (score 2):

your both codes aren't equivalent

```
point = {'features':[.4,1,3,.01,.1], 'label': 1}
```

you're passing a dictionary of lists instead of the value. When iterated upon, the dictionary yields *strings*. You mean:

```
p = predict(model, point['features'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Great read: [How to debug small programs (#2)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)  - set a breakpoint inside your `dot()` sum and inspect what datatypes are in `X && Y` when  using

```
return sum(i[0] * i[1] for i in zip(X, Y)
```

when you supply a dict as `Y` to it in your test method.